# Error in next.config.js when attempting to use appDir and withPWA

Tags: javascript, next.js

next.config.js setup like this with next-pwa and app experiment.

```
const withPWA = require('next-pwa');

module.exports = withPWA({
  pwa: {
    dest: 'public',
    disable: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
  },
  experimental: {
    appDir: true
  },
});
```

Getting error:
`Error: > The` app`directory is experimental. To enable, add`appDir: true`to your`next.config.js`configuration under`experimental`. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/experimental-app-dir-config`

Tried a newly created project, ensured that the config SHOULD work

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get it running because of some compiler errors within the PWA package (i assume it doesn't support v13 yet) but the issue was that you were defining `experimental` in the PWA config, and not in the `next.config.js`,

```
const withPWA = require("next-pwa")({
  pwa: {
    dest: "public",
    disable: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
  },
});

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = withPWA({
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
});

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Here is a good GH issue to follow: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/39161